# Keeping a Java ActionListener running once it's handled an event?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jlist

I have a `JList` of users, and whenever an element in the list is selected, I store the index of that element in an int. Then a `JButton` `ActionListener` will listen for a press of the "delete user" button, and will delete the user at that element of the list. Problem is, once it does this initially, the `ActionListener` stops running, so if I wish to delete another element, the button will no longer do anything. How do I ensure that the event handler keeps running even after it's already done something once? Here's my code for reference:

```
/*
 * Listener for user list selection
 */
userList.addListSelectionListener(
    new ListSelectionListener () {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            delete.setEnabled(true);
            index = userList.getSelectedIndex();
        }
    }
);

   /*
    * Listener for delete button press
    */
    delete.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int i = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            "Are you sure you want to delete user " + users.get(index) + "?");
            switch(i) {
                case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:

                try {
                    Controller.deleteUser(users.get(index));
                    users.remove(index);
                    listModel.removeElementAt(index);
                    userList = new JList(listModel);
                }

                catch (UserNotFoundException e1) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted -- are you saying that somehow the delete button does nothing the 2nd time you click it? Do you see any exceptions printed on the console?

Comment: No exceptions. The delete button just doesn't do anything the second time I click it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is you are setting a whole new userList from within the delete handler.

**Quick fix:** add your list event handler to the new JList

**Proper fix:** refactor so you don't need to do  `userList = new JList(listModel);` in the delete handler.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Didn't even realize that. I'm gonna do the quick fix for now :)

Comment: Turns out I don't even need to re-initialize userList. I was under the assumption that the list wouldn't refresh by itself. Apparently, it does. Problem solved!

Comment: +1, I totally overlooked the fact that the OP was creating a new list.